# How to get specify id from the url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have url like :

```
    http://localhost/index/2/99
```

through jquery or javascript i want to get the id 2 how can i get this value

i used like:

```
var url=document.URL;
alert(url.match(/\d+/));
```

output is:8000

Comment: `url.match(/\d+/)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: See properties from `window.location`. You might have to do splitting like `.split('/');`

Comment: use libraries like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-matcher` with pattern `http://localhost/index/:firstId/:secondId`

Comment: @MeetZaveri I was going to suggest the same. This will definitely work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the url path and get the value by index.

```js
var url = window.location.href.split('/');
console.log(url[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value by using index. url.match(/\d+/) gives you an array You can get it by index position like following:

```js
var url = "http://localhost/index/2/99";
var value = url.match(/\d+/);
console.log(value[0]);
```